# Run a script only once in BGE

Tags: python, game-engine

I have a script that I only need to run once. What I usually do for startup scripts is an *Always > Tap Sensor*. This python script is being activated by a message sensor with the tap setting enabled. Running this script multiple times will cause problems, so I used a variable system to prevent this from happening.

Is there anyway to stop the script from running more than once in the first place, using logic bricks?

Comment: with an accountant, or a property becomes false, or a value that compares if a property is of particular value

Comment: Can you please expound on this comment?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

For a script that only runs once, say a setup script, you can use an *Always* Sensor without True level triggering (the buttons outlined in red in the image below). Doing so will unintuitively to the *Always Sensor's* name will only run once.
[image: always sensor]

---

As for scripts where you only want a function to run once, but the rest constantly evaluated, I would highly recommend using The *Python* Controller in *Module* mode.
[image: Python Controller in Module mode]
The way it works is you pass in the name of your script (must have a `.py`), then the name of the function. So in the picture my script is named `script.py` and the function I am calling is `functionName`.

---

The final way is to use a variable, or property.

```
import bge  

cont = bge.logic.getCurrentController()
own = cont.owner

if 'init' not in own: # Will only run once, or when the var gets removed
    own['init'] = True
    print('only once')
```

Then if you need that code to run again use this line `del own['init']`.

Comment: So if I don't click on one of those three dots, it will only run once?  Thanks!

Comment: @AnsonSavage yep, by default the *Always* sensor only runs once.

Comment: Oh, so if I don't click on the three dots on my message sensor, the python controller that is connected will only be run one time?  Nice!

Answer (score 4):

What do you think about setting a static variable, like a Property, in Blender at the end of the Script that prevents it from running again ?

For more Details see:
[How to Set a Property Value in Blender Game Engine?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/461/how-to-set-a-property-value-in-blender-game-engine)

Comment: Please avoid link only answers; cite the relevant parts of the link so your answer can be understood without following the link, and add the link at the end for further information.

Comment: This is currently what I'm doing. Thank you for your input.

Comment: @AnsonSavage what is the drawback of this method (using a variable ) ? do you have a mush more complicated case ?

Comment: There's not a problem with it, I was just expecting the tap option to make it only run one time.  This question really isn't that important, I just put bounty on it just to see how much publicity it gets.  Thanks!

Comment: Using a variable (IE named init, boolean) and check it on start up, and set it to true when complete, is the de-facto method to run once. I've seen this method used in many tutorials and used it myself.